# Webpack dev server: How to redirect a localhost port to a URL of a different port

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Hi all I am trying to integrate a React project into an AngularJS project so that we can start progressively porting code from AngularJS to React.

When I run `npm run start`:

- the AngularJS instance starts and points to localhost:9001
- The React instance starts and points to localhost:8001

My end goal is to be able to embed sections of the ReactJS app into the AngularJS app via iframes. Right now I would be able to do it by putting `http://localhost:8001/some-route` as the iframe source. But it would be great if I could just do `/react/some-route`.
Wondering if there is a way to configure webpack dev server to redirect all requests from `http://localhost:8001` to `http://localhost:9001/react`

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly easy way to configure webpack:

### `devServer.proxy`

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
  }
};
```

(I don't even think it needs more explanation than that.)

Comment: That's great thank you so much, there must be something other that I'm missing because it does not work, maybe some other bit of config to tell angular to not handle that route or something like that.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I should have kept my trap shut, angular not being my thing. Anyway, I think this looks promising: https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: The issue here is that it is not a `redirect` it is a proxy, therefore Host and Origin will be as on the front-end, no the ones as api have.